# Splitting text in cells into separate rows

Tags: macos, microsoft-excel, vba

I came across this code a while back, it works perfectly, but I would like to make a few modifications to it to reflect what I want. I have tinkered with this code for a while and so far I was unable to sort it out on my own and need help.

Orignal question Link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19815321/text-to-rows-vba-excel

```
Option Explicit

Sub Main()

    Columns("B:B").NumberFormat = "@"
    Dim i As Long, c As Long, r As Range, v As Variant

    For i = 1 To Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        v = Split(Range("B" & i), "/")
        c = c + UBound(v) + 1
    Next i

    For i = 2 To c
        Set r = Range("B" & i)
        Dim arr As Variant
        arr = Split(r, "/")
        Dim j As Long
        r = arr(0)
        For j = 1 To UBound(arr)
            Rows(r.Row + j & ":" & r.Row + j).Insert Shift:=xlDown
            r.Offset(j, 0) = arr(j)
            r.Offset(j, -1) = r.Offset(0, -1)
            r.Offset(j, 1) = r.Offset(0, 1)
        Next j
    Next i

End Sub
```

How can I change this code If I have more columns that need to be sorted the way that this code sorts the data currently. Because at the moment it only processes 3 columns to the left and right of column 'B'.

I don't know if i'm being vague or not but I really don't know how to explain my problem. Any and all help will be appreciated.

Comment: @Meehow or if anyone else knows how to do this.

Comment: Do you need it split up based on more than one column or do the other columns just follow the original split?

Comment: @Raystafarian The other columns follow the original split, please. 

Because this code works perfectly, but is only applicable to 3 columns (there is a picture in the original question link). I would like this to be done on all the columns I have not just to the left and right of Column 'B'.

Comment: You aren't making sense. So for instance you have something in column D and you want it to replicate down column d each time there's a split?

Comment: @Raystafarian Yes, I would like it to replicate down into the next row in accordance with the original row (as shown in the the second picture in the original link - sorry I need more points to post pictures here). 

For instance, if column D has birthdates, Column E has Location and Column F has their address, I would like that to be replicated just like Column A and C does in the code/Picture.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You change this bit of the code -

```
r.Offset(j, 0) = arr(j)
r.Offset(j, -1) = r.Offset(0, -1)
r.Offset(j, 1) = r.Offset(0, 1)
```

to include the additional columns -

```
r.Offset(j, 0) = arr(j)
r.Offset(j, -1) = r.Offset(0, -1)
r.Offset(j, 1) = r.Offset(0, 1)
r.Offset(j, 2) = r.Offset(0, 2)
r.Offset(j, 3) = r.Offset(0, 3)
r.Offset(j, 4) = r.Offset(0, 4)
```

Or, in other words, you offset by *n* where *n* can be positive or negative (right/left or down/up) by putting it in the `offset()` function.

Comment: Okay, i'll test and report.

Comment: That worked perfectly! Thank you so very much for your help. Sorry if my question was vague, I am new to this and didn't know how to structure my thoughts. Appreciate it!

Comment: I am getting a runtime error '9': SubScript out of range. Is there a way around it?

Comment: What line is the error on?

Comment: The yellow highlights are on the following:

 v = Split(Range("E" & i), " ")
        c = c + UBound(v) + 1
    Next i

Comment: I don't see that in this code.

Comment: I edited the code to meet my requirements... How can I send you the code im using?

Comment: I have switched 'B' to 'E' and changed "/" to " "

Comment: Then you'll need to fix all of the code with your changes

Comment: Okay... where do I start?

Comment: I hate to keep bugging you and I apologize for doing so, but is there any solution to the problem. Ive been tinkering around with the code for a while with no luck whatsoever. Ive been trying to frankenstein code from different places to get around the error... no luck.

Comment: If you changed one B, change all the Bs

Comment: I did that, but there is still an error.

Comment: I have added the "dim WS sheet1" to help solve this issue, but still nothing. Is there anything else I can do?

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/Aa264519%28v=VS.60%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Comment: Thank you for that, I tried again but cant seem to work it. I am not a coder/developer, not by a long shot. I'm just someone trying to keep his job. 

like i said, im trying to Frankenstein the hell out of this code but i get nothing but errors because I dont know what im doing. :(

Comment: You don't have enough rep to enter a chat room, so all I can say is post another question asking what the issue is - include the error message and the lines it errors on and what you've tried.

Comment: I did what you asked. Thank you for the suggestion.

http://superuser.com/questions/951912/subscript-out-of-range-error-9