# (Subscript out of range) Error 9

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, macros

Below is a modified version of a code (i found on Stack Exchange) that I am currently using -

```
Option Explicit

Sub Main()

    Columns("E:E").NumberFormat = "@"
    Dim i As Long, c As Long, r As Range, v As Variant

    For i = 2 To Range("E" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        v = Split(Range("E" & i), " ")
        c = c + UBound(v) + 1
    Next i

    For i = 2 To c
        Set r = Range("E" & i)
        Dim arr As Variant
        arr = Split(r, " ")
        Dim j As Long
        r = arr(0)
        For j = 1 To UBound(arr)
            Rows(r.Row + j & ":" & r.Row + j).Insert Shift:=xlDown
            r.Offset(j, 0) = arr(j)
r.Offset(j, -1) = r.Offset(0, -1)
r.Offset(j, -2) = r.Offset(0, -2)
r.Offset(j, -3) = r.Offset(0, -3)
r.Offset(j, 1) = r.Offset(0, 1)
r.Offset(j, 2) = r.Offset(0, 2)
r.Offset(j, 3) = r.Offset(0, 3)
r.Offset(j, 4) = r.Offset(0, 4)


        Next j
    Next i

End Sub
```

Now the problem with this code is that it gives me an error (Subscript out of range) Error 9.

To explain what I am trying to do: I have multiple data in individual cells that I would like to split into separate rows. Now this code works well, but the code does not run throughout the Sheet and stops at a few entries.

To see an example: please follow the link to understand what the code does. (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19815321/text-to-rows-vba-excel) - Sorry I don't have enough points to add pictures.

Please understand that I am very new at this and don't know what I am doing for the most part.

Thank you.

Comment: I am really not sure what C even is... The yellow highlighted code are as follows: **v = Split(Range("E" & i), " ")
        c = c + UBound(v) + 1
    Next i**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It only breaks for me when the range is blank - so I added an `if`

```
Option Explicit

Sub Main()

    Columns("E:E").NumberFormat = "@"
    Dim i As Long, c As Long, r As Range, v As Variant

    For i = 2 To Range("E" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        v = Split(Range("E" & i), " ")
        c = c + UBound(v) + 1
    Next i

    For i = 2 To c
        If Range("E" & i) <> "" Then
        Set r = Range("E" & i)
        Dim arr As Variant
        arr = Split(r, " ")
        Dim j As Long
        r = arr(0)
        For j = 1 To UBound(arr)
            Rows(r.Row + j & ":" & r.Row + j).Insert Shift:=xlDown
            r.Offset(j, 0) = arr(j)
            r.Offset(j, -1) = r.Offset(0, -1)
            r.Offset(j, -2) = r.Offset(0, -2)
            r.Offset(j, -3) = r.Offset(0, -3)
            r.Offset(j, 1) = r.Offset(0, 1)
            r.Offset(j, 2) = r.Offset(0, 2)
            r.Offset(j, 3) = r.Offset(0, 3)
            r.Offset(j, 4) = r.Offset(0, 4)
        Next j
        End If
    Next i

End Sub
```

So, your data must have some double spaces in it where it breaks? Or something where you end up with blanks in column E.

---

You can use this snippet to remove your extra spaces in column E (my bad)

```
Sub test()
Dim c As Range
Dim lastrow As Integer
lastrow = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, "E").End(xlUp).Row
Dim strValue As String
For Each c In Range("E2:E" & lastrow)
    strValue = c.Value
    Do While InStr(1, strValue, "  ")
        strValue = Replace(strValue, "  ", " ")
    Loop
    c = strValue
Next
End Sub
```

Comment: I really cannot thank you enough. I looked over my data again and thats exactly what you said it was. I had double and in some cases triple spaces as well between entries. 

I have been tinkering with the code all day long with no luck... I was desperate so I tried removing `r = arr(0)` and it kind of worked but it was still very messy. You are a star, Thank you for helping me out and potentially keeping my job. 

I know you helped me previously as well in my last question, So thank you for that as well! :)

Comment: if the questions were about the same data, then it's my previous solution that's causing the consecutive spaces..

Comment: @Jase Check my answer, I added a little routine that will remove the extra spaces from column E so you don't run into this again. There shouldn't be any leading or trailing spaces as the other routine gives you the array with `trim()`

Comment: I just tested it out and the second code works perfectly! Thank you so much! This saved me so much time! Really, you have made my life easier! Thank you so much!